# IIS 401.3 With Windows Authentication 2016

Tags: windows, iis, server, http-status-code-401

I am moving some old web applications from an old Server to a Server 2016.  We are using a domain account for the application identity and we need to use windows authentication.  I am getting a 401.3 error when I try a test.html page on the server.  I am only getting this for static content though as I tried a home.aspx page and that page worked.

Things I have tried/checked

- Static Content is installed under the Common HTTP Features
- The domain account used for the app pool has full access to the directory containing test.html
- Tried NTLM first as provider instead of Negotiate on IIS Windows Authentication Providers
- Tried "Enable Kernel-mode authentication" checked and unchecked
- Tried all settings of "Extended Protection" under Advanced settings for windows authentication.
- Tried ProcMon.  All I get when I filter for test.html is 2 QueryOpen operations with result SUCCESS

Comment: Add Authenticated Users to Users group. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webtopics/2009/06/25/troubleshooting-http-401-3-errors-with-process-monitor/

Comment: Just checked it and it looks like Authenticated Users was already in the Users group

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this was that we need to have the account that was running the application pool set up in the "Impersonate a client after authentication."  Our local group policy had this locked down.  I am guessing the default install may have IIS_USRS group in this policy but our server did not.